# .net Access to Message Queuing system is denied (Windows 7/Windows Server 2008)

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, msmq

I currently have MSMQ server (windows 2008) which is responsible for distributing messages to all of our client machines, these client machines are running Windows 7. The majority of our clients happily send and receive messages from the queues, however some receive an "access to message queuing system is denied" message when attempt to receive the next message, it is also worth pointing out that these machines can send messages to the queue successfully. I have tried everything that I can think of to resolve issue but have yet been able to find a solution.

We are accessing the MSMQ from within a windows forms c# application. I have tried the following to resolve the issue:

1. Added the "EnablePingService" registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security" and set the value to 1 on the server
2. Added the "NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient" registry key into the same location and set the value to 1 on the server
3. Enable the "Remote Administration (RPC-EPMAP) inbound firewall rule on the server, followed by completely turning off the firewalls on both machines
4. Added the permissions "Everyone", "ANOMUMOUS LOGON", "SYSTEM", "[the clients local user]" to the individual queues with full control so all features
5. Ensure that the "Disable un-authenticated RPC calls" setting was unchecked on the server MSMQ machine
6. Changed the connection string in c# to run in both TCP and OS mode when sending and receiving messages

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Are you accessing the queues directly with `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` or using a library / framework that sits on top?

Comment: Also, after making all of these changes I trust you have restarted the server because MSMQ only picks up the Registry changes on start-up, not mid-run... Worth pointing that one out!

Comment: Finally, this article has some good pointers on why send works and read doesn't = http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008.aspx Let me know if any of the above comments work and I will flesh out an answer.

Comment: Belogix - thanks for the quick response. Yes, i'm using System.Messaging.MessageQueue and restarted the server once I made the registry changes. It's worth pointing out that I only made the registry changes on the server and not the client machines.

Comment: regards the suggested article, I tried what was suggesting in there with no success.

Comment: Okay, if you log the exception, in the inner exception you should have `_HResult`, what code is that?

Comment: -2146233079, I googled it but didn't see much about it

Comment: Can you confirm that the clients that work vs the clients that don't work have the same version of Windows (service packs and all installed)? This looks like it might be MSMQ version mismatches.

Comment: I logged in using a different user on the problem machine and was able to receive a message from the MSMQ. This has confirmed that it is likely to be a user specific permissions issue on the machine, however I can't track down anything that could be causing it. Any ideas? UAC is turned off.